# Complex logarithm integral conditions

Tags: integration

Describe conditions for the integral of $log(z)$ along a closed curve $\gamma$ to be zero.

Edit:

I think I only need to test where the function is not analytical, and there you should see my restrictions. But there I feel lost.

Comment: There is no such condition on curves as "homotopic". You have to indicate what it is homotopic to.

Comment: Yes, I read that right, and what I said I thought is wrong, I only need to test where the function is not analytical, and there you should see my restrictions.

Comment: The answer here is going to depend on what exactly you mean by "$\log(z)$". If you mean some branch of $\log z$, then the curve cannot cross the branch line. However, if you mean the multi-valued function, the condition is more advanced, and can be expressed in terms of homotopy or winding number.

Comment: I think it is in terms of homotopy I have not seen anything about winding number yet. Thank you